# MongoDB/Mongoose How to add elements in a complex structure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, document

I've this complex structure in a project I'm working on, and I can't find a way to bulk add some values in the "parametri" array.

Here is an example document:

[image]

My goal is to add some values to "parametri" array that is inside the Object at position 1 of the array "protocolli".

In mongoDB Compass I can do a select using "'protocolli.nome': 'protocollo-2'", so I've tried the following code (the project is written in TS, uses a NestJs backend and Mongoose to communicate with MongoDB):

```
  this.model.updateMany(
       { 'protocolli.nome': ProtocolloAlert.PROTOCOLLO_2 },
       {
         $push: {
           'protocolli.parametri': {
             $each: [
               TipoParametro.FAT_MASS,
               TipoParametro.DISTANCE,
               TipoParametro.MUSCLE_MASS,
               TipoParametro.STEPS,
               TipoParametro.CALORIES,
               TipoParametro.MINUTES,
             ],
           },
         },
       },
       { multi: true }
     )
```

I've already tried $push, $addToSet, $set with no positive result..

Using this method, I've the following error:

MongoError: Cannot create field 'parametri' in element {protocolli: [ { nome: "protocollo-1", parametri: [ "temp", "spo2", "hr", "sys" ], descrizione: "Attivazione alert in control room, inserimento nei log degli alert in corso, salvataggio nella scheda alert del paziente" }, { nome: "protocollo-2", parametri: [ "dya", "pulse", "fr", "pef", "fev1", "fvc", "fev1fvc", "etco2", "freqRes", "glucose", "weight", "height", "bmi", "bodyFat", "hba1c", "totCh", "triglycerides", "hdl", "ldl" ], descrizione: "Salvataggio nella scheda alert del paziente" } ]}
at Function.create (C:....\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: You don't need `{ multi: true }` at `updateMany` - as the command name implies.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comments, but multi: true is irrelevant for my problem... and I've used a screenshot only for the DB because it was unreadable otherwise